# Building Ionic Cordova ios via Azure DevOps

Tags: ios, xcode, cordova, azure-devops

Does anyone have an idea how to use Azure DevOps CI with an ionic cordova ios app?

I tried the following

- Npm install
- Ionic command (Command: ionic cordova build ios)
- List item
- Install an apple certificate
- Install an apple provisioning profile
- Xcode build
- Publish to the app store (install from marketplace)

Xcode build fails with the following error

```
2020-05-06T22:29:39.9577800Z ##[section]Starting: Xcode build
2020-05-06T22:29:39.9594120Z ==============================================================================
2020-05-06T22:29:39.9594470Z Task         : Xcode
2020-05-06T22:29:39.9594850Z Description  : Build, test, or archive an Xcode workspace on macOS. Optionally package an app.
2020-05-06T22:29:39.9595210Z Version      : 5.152.0
2020-05-06T22:29:39.9595490Z Author       : Microsoft Corporation
2020-05-06T22:29:39.9595850Z Help         : https://learn.microsoft.com/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/xcode
2020-05-06T22:29:39.9596310Z ==============================================================================
2020-05-06T22:29:48.0466510Z ##[warning]Multiple Xcode workspace matches were found. The first match will be used: /Users/runner/runners/2.166.4/work/1/s/node_modules/@capacitor/cli/assets/ios-template/App/App.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace
2020-05-06T22:29:48.0482290Z [command]/usr/bin/xcodebuild -workspace /Users/runner/runners/2.166.4/work/1/s/node_modules/@capacitor/cli/assets/ios-template/App/App.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace -list
2020-05-06T22:29:53.0861170Z Information about workspace "App":
2020-05-06T22:29:53.0861630Z     Schemes:
2020-05-06T22:29:53.0866440Z         App
2020-05-06T22:29:53.0866690Z 
2020-05-06T22:29:53.1010390Z The workspace contains a single shared scheme. 'App' will be used.
2020-05-06T22:29:53.1033230Z [command]/usr/bin/xcodebuild -version
2020-05-06T22:29:53.2107930Z Xcode 10.3
2020-05-06T22:29:53.2127580Z Build version 10G8
2020-05-06T22:29:53.2275010Z [command]/usr/bin/xcodebuild -sdk iphonesimulator12.4 -configuration Release -workspace /Users/runner/runners/2.166.4/work/1/s/node_modules/@capacitor/cli/assets/ios-template/App/App.xcodeproj/project.xcworkspace -scheme App build CODE_SIGN_STYLE=Automatic DEVELOPMENT_TEAM=XXXX | /usr/local/lib/ruby/gems/2.6.0/bin/xcpretty -r junit --no-color
2020-05-06T22:29:54.8861040Z 
2020-05-06T22:29:54.8863380Z âŒ  error: /Users/runner/runners/2.166.4/work/1/s/node_modules/@capacitor/cli/assets/ios-template/App/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App.release.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "App" in project "App") (in target 'App')
2020-05-06T22:29:54.8864420Z 
2020-05-06T22:29:54.8866300Z 
2020-05-06T22:29:54.8868760Z 
2020-05-06T22:29:54.8871220Z âŒ  error: /Users/runner/runners/2.166.4/work/1/s/node_modules/@capacitor/cli/assets/ios-template/App/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App.release.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "App" in project "App") (in target 'App')
2020-05-06T22:29:54.8872120Z 
2020-05-06T22:29:54.8872340Z 
2020-05-06T22:29:54.8878940Z 
2020-05-06T22:29:54.8880320Z âŒ  error: /Users/runner/runners/2.166.4/work/1/s/node_modules/@capacitor/cli/assets/ios-template/App/Pods/Target Support Files/Pods-App/Pods-App.release.xcconfig: unable to open file (in target "App" in project "App") (in target 'App')
2020-05-06T22:29:54.8880960Z 
2020-05-06T22:29:54.8881090Z 
2020-05-06T22:29:54.8891460Z ** BUILD FAILED **
2020-05-06T22:29:54.8892100Z 
2020-05-06T22:29:54.9074960Z ##[error]Error: /usr/bin/xcodebuild failed with return code: 65
2020-05-06T22:29:54.9432910Z ##[section]Finishing: Xcode build
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I resolved this error by removing capacitor

[how to remove capacitor](https://ionic-5-full-starter-app-docs.ionicthemes.com/capacitor)

Comment: Great! Thanks for sharing your solution here, you could [Accept it as an Answer](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/01/06/accept-your-own-answers/) , so it could help other community members who get the same issues and we could archive this thread, thanks.

Comment: @user10056111 I would like to see your build definition.  Would really help if you could provide images.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to build Azure Devops Pipeline for iOS and Android. You would need to

1. Install Node JS
2. Install Ionic
3. Call `ionic capacitor sync`
4. Add `Cocoapods Install` task to your working directory
5. Configure your project path
6. Build iOS or Android

For those who are looking for YAML templates, please find a detailed version [here](https://www.dhilip.tech/ionic/2020/06/18/AzureYAML-Ionic.html)